# Openlayers 6 in Vue3 application not working properly

Tags: openlayers, vue.js

I have a vue3 app with a simple openlayers map, but anytime I try and add the source as a ref, and reference it in the onMounted hook, an error is generated in the console:

```
events.js?781a:63 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: target.addEventListener is not a function
    at listen (events.js?781a:63:1)
    at LayerGroup.registerLayerListeners_ (Group.js?4337:182:1)
    at LayerGroup.handleLayersChanged_ (Group.js?4337:172:1)
    at LayerGroup.dispatchEvent (Target.js?363c:113:1)
    at LayerGroup.notify (Object.js?1b38:176:1)
    at LayerGroup.set (Object.js?1b38:215:1)
    at LayerGroup.setLayers (Group.js?4337:271:1)
    at new LayerGroup (Group.js?4337:141:1)
    at createOptionsInternal (Map.js?985a:1752:1)
    at new Map (Map.js?985a:259:1)
```

Here is the full code:

```
<template>
  <div id="map-root"
       style="width:100%; height:100%">
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import View from 'ol/View'
import Map from 'ol/Map'
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM'
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector'
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector'
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON'
import 'ol/ol.css'

const olMap = ref(null);
const vectorLayer = ref(null);

const data = {
  type: 'Feature',
  properties: {},
  geometry: {
    type: 'Polygon',
    coordinates: [
      [
        [
          -27.0703125,
          43.58039085560784
        ],
        [
          -28.125,
          23.563987128451217
        ],
        [
          -10.8984375,
          32.84267363195431
        ],
        [
          -27.0703125,
          43.58039085560784
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
};
const updateSource = () => {
  const view = olMap.value.getView();
  const source = vectorLayer.value.getSource();
  const features = new GeoJSON({
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
  }).readFeatures(data);
  source.clear();
  source.addFeatures(features);
  view.fit(source.getExtent())
}
const initMap = () => {
  // a new vector layer is created with the feature
  vectorLayer.value = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
      features: [],
    }),
  })
  olMap.value = new Map({
    target: "map-root",
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM() // tiles are served by OpenStreetMap
      }),
        vectorLayer
    ],
    view: new View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
    })
  })
  updateSource();
}

onMounted(() => {
  initMap();

})

</script>
```

If I change the creation of the vector layer to:

```
const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({
      features: [],
    }),
  })
```

the map loads, but the console complains about the source:

```
OLMap.vue?3f6a:50 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSource')
```

which is this line of code:

```
const source = vectorLayer.value.getSource();
```

How do I add the source and also have the ability to access it to add features, delete features, add style, etc?

Comment: If you defined you layer as `vectorLayer.value` you must use `vectorLayer.value`  in the layerrs array in the map constructor

Comment: @Mike Thank you!  Not sure how I overlooked that and spent that much time troubleshooting.  :|